# Importing async gone wrong

Tags: python

I am importing async file package which I installed from python.org. But when I import it it shows

> "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"

My pycharm says that an identifier before "async" and "'def' or 'with' or 'for' is expected after async. What can I do? Code is given below:

```
from . import async, constants, exceptions, utils
```

I will be very thankful if anybody helped me.

Comment: Python thinks that async is a keyword

Comment: Can you please show your code?

Comment: Rename your async module to something different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `async` keyword is used for defining coroutines

[Click here to read about Coroutines and Tasks](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html)

I would recommend renaming your `async` module to something different, and then importing the module with the new name

Comment: It worked. Thank you very much. I am very grateful for your help. I changed the name and it worked like magic.